# How to sum elements in list of dictionaries if two or more key values are the same

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I have the following array of dictionaries:

```
[{name:'g1', variant:'v1', count:1},{name:'g2', variant:'v1', count:2}, {name:'g1', variant:'v1', count:2}, {name:'g2', variant:'v1', count:2}]
```

I want to create a new list of dictionaries given an array 
`['name', 'variant']`, such that, if two dictionaries have the same values for the keys given in the array, the corresponding count is added up as follows:

```
[{name:'g1', variant:'v1', count:3},{name:'g2', variant:'v1', count:4}]
```

How can I achieve this in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` method to group by and then sum `count`:

```
const result = arr.reduce((a, {name, variant, count}) => {
  a[name] = a[name] || {name, variant, count: 0};
  a[name].count += count;
  return a;
}, {})
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [
  {name:'g1', variant:'v1', count:1},
  {name:'g2', variant:'v1', count:2}, 
  {name:'g1', variant:'v1', count:2}, 
  {name:'g2', variant:'v1', count:2}
];   

const result = arr.reduce((a, {name, variant, count}) => {
  a[name] = a[name] || {name, variant, count: 0};
  a[name].count += count;
  return a;
}, {})

console.log(Object.values(result))
```

**UPDATE:**

In case of you want to group by multiple properties such as `name` and `variant`, then you can use:

```
const result = [...arr.reduce((r, o) => {

  const key = o.name + '-' + o.variant;

  const item = r.get(key) || Object.assign({}, o, {
    count: 0
  });

  item.count += +o.count;

  return r.set(key, item);
}, new Map).values()];
```

An example:

```js
let arr = [
  {name:'g1', variant:'v1', count:1},
  {name:'g2', variant:'v1', count:2},
  {name:'g1', variant:'v1', count:2},
  {name:'g2', variant:'v1', count:2}
];


const result = [...arr.reduce((r, o) => {

  const key = o.name + '-' + o.variant;

  const item = r.get(key) || Object.assign({}, o, {
    count: 0
  });

  item.count += +o.count;

  return r.set(key, item);
}, new Map).values()];

console.log(result);
```

Without hardcoding keys:

```
let firstKey = 'name', secondKey = 'variant', thirdKey = 'count';

const result = [...arr.reduce((r, o) => {

  const key = o[firstKey] + '-' + o[secondKey];

  const item = r.get(key) || Object.assign({}, o, {
    [thirdKey]: 0
  });

  item[thirdKey] += +o[thirdKey];

  return r.set(key, item);
}, new Map).values()];
```

Comment: I think the OP wants to check if the values of both `name` and `variant` are the same, something like `a[name + variant] = a[name + variant] ||  .....`.

Comment: Can we do this without hardcoding the key names?

Comment: @StepUp In the example, count is hardcoded.

Comment: @al27 I've edited the reply